# Transfer Blockchain.info to Electrum

Tags: blockchain.info, electrum, multi-signature

I am moving to Electrum from Blockchain, but I can't find any guides or tutorials on the internet that explain the process of tranferring a Blockchain wallet to Electrum. I have a multi-signature wallet by the way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to move these funds is simly run both wallets and transfer the funds in a regular transaction.

For safety sake keep a backup of your old Blockchain wallet as you may find out in the future that you need the keys such that a service may have sent funds to a preregistered address or someone reused an old address.

Remember to create a backup of your new seed which Electrum will provide to you.